# Matching URL with multiple parameters Django

Tags: django, django-urls

Here what i am trying to accomplish is to get URL parameters value from the URL

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/sample/redirect_login/?request_token=9I0KoKcgdKH0s6w1Qzp6t5P2czlyxPum&action=login&status=success
```

I have created similar URL path in my urls.py but looks like they are not matching

```
path('redirect_login/?request_token=<str:request_token>&action=<str:action>&status=<str:status>',views.redirectLogin, name = "redirectLogin"),
```

I want to get the parameters 1. request_token 2. action 3. Status

Kindly help how to go about this? Should i be using REGEX for url matching ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In urls.py you should do:

```
path('redirect_login/',views.redirectLogin, name = "redirectLogin"),
```

And then to get parameters in view:

```
request_token = request.GET.get('request_token', '')
action = request.GET.get('action', '')
status = request.GET.get('status', '')
```